# Get particular range of values in LinkedHashMap with start and end key

Tags: java, iteration, linkedhashmap

I have 2 Maps like below

```
    LinkedHashMap<String,String> m1 = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
    Map<String,String> m2 = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

I need to get values from both of the maps but for `m2` I have to get range(sets) of values with a range between 1st and 2nd... 2nd and 3rd key of m1(m1 keys available in m2). How can I achieve that?

```
for(Map.Entry<String,String> m: m1.entrySet()){
    String curKey = m.getKey();
    String curVal = m.getValue();
    //Write values in file
    //get values with the range between start=curKey and end=nextKey from m2 map
    //Write m2 map values in file
}
```

Comment: Anyone please edit my question, I cannot edit in my PC

Comment: Just did so. But why can't you edit?

Comment: I Don't know dude, I followed the rules (4 spaces). But it doesn't get affaected

Comment: But you didn't follow the other rule (empty line before a block of code)...

Comment: Oh ok dude, I will follow going forward. Can you answer for my question

Comment: This is not really a thing you can do.  Not with these data structures.  "Between" is not really a thing these data structures support.